# Force CSS to load through standard HTTP on Github?

Tags: http, https, github

As you may know, Github forces an HTTPS connection. How could I force the **stylesheets** to load through a standard HTTP connection?

This is because I am behind a school firewall, and the HTTPS version of the stylesheets is blocked, but the HTTP version isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a Greasemonkey script to rewrite the URIs for the css files?

Comment: Could you include said script? I don't know the first thing about greasemonkey.

Comment: Do you have sufficient permissions to install addons/extensions? FF or Chrome?

Comment: Have you come up with a script yet?

Comment: No I haven't tried, it's been done before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=greasemonkey+firefox+rewrite+url